flask return async generator in async endpoint
Flask allows streaming content using generators.
But, I can't stream content using an async generator in an async endpoint. Here's an example:
from flask import Flask, Response
import asyncio

app = Flask(__name__)

async def generate_data():
    for i in range(5):
        yield f"Data: {i}\n"
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

@app.route('/stream')
async def stream():
    return Response(generate_data(), mimetype='text/plain')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=3030)

which gives this error:
╰─$ python test.py 
 * Serving Flask app 'test'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3030
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 899-865-629
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ashkan/Downloads/flask-async-test/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 256, in __next__
    return self._next()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ashkan/Downloads/flask-async-test/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/response.py", line 32, in _iter_encoded
    for item in iterable:
                ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Oct/2024 23:30:58] "GET /stream HTTP/1.1" 200 -


Not an answer, but I would strongly consider using FastAPI instead of flask, especially for async servers.

There is a fundamental difference between async generators and sync generators.  The async variety can only be iterated with the assistance of the event loop, which implies a different mechanism.  Async generators are iterated with the anext function, which returns an awaitable as opposed to a value.  Typically that means it would be called inside an async def function.  Sync generators are iterated with the next function, which simply returns a value.  I don't know if Flask supports what you want to do.
